# Unity assets turned binary from text

Tags: unity, git

I'm working with unity and `git`, and for some reason, from some point - the assets started being `Binary` files, meaning that they're not visible as normal `YAML` files, and I cannot see textual `git diff` results on them.

Has anyone experiences it and knows how to revert to the textual format from the binary format?

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47836334/convert-unity-settings-from-binary-to-text

This post has the answer. Apparently, I have some bugs with the unity editor that I've encountered, which show something in the Edtior, but is actually something different in the backend.

In my case, it was set to `Mixed` (Probably), while still showing `Force Text` in the `Edtior Settings`.

The fix was to set it to something other than `Force Text`, forcing it to reimport the assets,
And then, set it again to `Force Text`, forcing the assets to be reimported as `Text`. Hurray!